# Functions results in angularjs view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*I'm afraid this question is pretty stupid....*

Using the `{{current.name}}` syntax I can show the `name` of `$scope.current` in the view. I set `current` when I switch from the list view (`/mythings`) to editing an item (`/mythings?id=someId`).

Actually this is redundant as I have the information both in the `$location` and in `$scope.current`. This redundancy makes it more complicated to understand, so I'd like to get rid of it.

I replaced `current` by a current item returning function and hoped it would work (like it does in many other cases). But it doesn't, I need to write `{{current().name}}` everywhere, which I tend to forget.

Maybe I'm doing it all wrong? I'm a beginner here.

Is there a way to make it work? Somehow bless `current` so it always gets evaluated before use?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. If you were on `/mythings`, what is it you want to see bound to the screen?

Comment: @drew_w: I don't really understand my question either.. I'm just a confused newbie here. But I hope, I explained the redundancy thing clearly. When I'm on `/mythings`, then there's nothing as there's no selected item (`current` is undefined). When I'm on `/mythings?id=someId`, then `current.id = someId`. This is the redundancy I wrote about. I could imagine `current` being a function returning the element with `$location.search('id')`.

Comment: You can have a different controller for list and the detail view. Then the detail view controller will only have current.

Comment: I don't really see that much of a redundancy. You either have to bind scope's property (`current`) to some value that already exists or you have to declare a new function (`current()`) and call it multiple times per digest loop. I think the second alternative introduces more redundancy than it avoids.

Comment: @ExpertSystem: My problem with the variable is that I have to keep it in sync with `$location.search` while the function would always produce the correct result. I was trying to remember if the last state of a page was "list" or "detail" by storing `current` in a service and it got out of sync with the location (no surprise). Then I tried to update the `$location.search` based on `current` and got lost. Maybe I just need a break... ;)

Comment: @maaartinus: OK, it makes sense. The function seems a reasonable (and simple) approach. What is the problem with that ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem: OK, if you think that it's reasonable, so I'll use it. And then delete this question... I was just too confused (many choices and no clear winner).

Comment: @maaartinus: I may have found a winner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both alternatives discussed have pros and cons:

1. Using a property (`current`) is easier (and more natural) to reference in the view, but it needs to be manually kept in sync with the location.
2. Using a function (`current()`) takes care of the keeping in sync issue, but is less intuitive.

All things considered, I would value the auto-syncing feature higher and go for the second alternative (`current()` function).

---

But, what if we could get a third option that combines the best of both worlds ?
And in fact we can :)

We can use the concept of **[Object Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)**, introduced by ECMAScript 5, and define some "computed properties" for our `$scope` (or service?).

Without getting into much detail (see the docs for more details), we could augment a scope like this:

```
.cotroller('someCtrl', function ($location, $scope) {
    Object.defineProperty($scope, 'current', {
        get: function () {
            return {
                name: $location.path();
                id: $location.search('id');
            };
        }
    });
```

Now, we can access `$scope.current.name` and `$scope.current.id` as if `current` were a normal property of `$scope` (intuitiveness !) and current will be automatically computed based on the current location (auto-sync !).
Thank you ECMAScript 5 :)

**[This article](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/02/computer-properties-with-javascript-properties/)** provides a simple and clear introduction to the concept.